# Webpack - How to include simple config file at runtime?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am new to webpack. For my project I have a config.js file. This file is basically like your web.config in .net. Just a simple config file that sets some environment specific settings. I want to be able to drop in a new config file per environment at the time of deployment. The issue I am running into is I do not always know what the config settings will be lets say two weeks down the road, so setting the config settings in the actual webpack config is not an option.

I add the config.js to the webpack config and it adds a hash and mapping to the config file. This makes it difficult to easily drop in a separate config file. We want to be able to bundle the project and deploy the artifacts to different environments without recompiling and bundling

Is there a way to just include a config file without hashing, bundling, and mapping? Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my current config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts',
    'config': './config/config.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
  ]
};
```

Comment: I may be missing the point of your question, but a webpack config file is just javascript. you can read things like environment variables which are useful for env specific runtimes. Also just to clarify you don't run webpack on prod servers traditionally, you run locally then upload built assets to a cdn

Comment: HI Andy what I am facing is adding a config after building the assets. I know that you can add environment specific variables in webpack. However, what if you do not know the exact environment variables until after building. So we will have the artifacts that need to be deployed and then someone adds an additional environment with different parameters. We do not want to have to recompile. To clarify the settings would be the same just different values per environment. Have you ran into anything like this?

Comment: Builds should be immutable and tested as such. If you have to recompile to add an environment there is a chance the artifacts would be different and have to be retested for every environment that is setup.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the only way to achieve this is to fetch the configuration on application startup.